# jQuery alert(this)?

Tags: jquery, alert

I want to do `alert(this)` for demo purposes (want to see what's 'this' within the code in different places).

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Right now it returns `[object Object]` only?

Comment: It depends what the object is and what part of it you want to display. You could use "var str = JSON.stringify(this); alert(str);"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this instead:

```js
console.log($(this));
```

The object will be displayed in the JavaScript console.

Comment: With firebug or web tools of Chrome.

Comment: Great trick! But it gave me bgColor, direction, dontChangeColor, fontSize etc. but I can't find the class/ID of this element.

Comment: You can do `console.log( this.id )` for id or   
`console.log( $(this).attr('class') )` to get the class. And alert would work if you just want to display those properties, but didn't work before because you were trying to alert a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(this));
```

This should work in a browser (not sure about old IE versions).

Comment: Once again, it returned something like: `{"width":182,"height":182,"bgColor":"transparent","fontSize":"14px","direction":"lr","toColor":"#999","speed":500,"top":236,"left":351,"target":null,"transparent":"transparent","dontChangeColor":false}` so I guess this script is generating something that have no class or id?